# Append Select List value to URL

Tags: html, forms, url, append, selectlist

I have a form that is nothing more than a select list that is displaying records from a database and a button.   All I want to do is when they select an option and click Submit, it takes them to a page that deletes the record in question.   To delete it - I need the tech_id (from the select list) to be appended to the URL.  I've done it the way I would with a text field, but that didn't work.  Any suggestions?

```
<form method="post" id="form1" name="form1" action="delete-tech.php?tech_id=<?php echo $_POST['technician']; ?>">
  <p>Choose Technician to Delete:
    <select name="technician" id="technician" title="technician">
      <?php
do {  
?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row_getTechs['tech_id']?>"><?php echo $row_getTechs['tech_name']?></option>
      <?php
} while ($row_getTechs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTechs));
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($getTechs);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysqli_data_seek($getTechs, 0);
      $row_getTechs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTechs);
  }
?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Delete Technician">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You need `method="GET"` in place of `method="post"`. Check the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in the coding construct.

I have slightly changed the position of a code segment following `while` statement as follows(i.e. placed it before the `do` phrase):

```
<form method="GET" id="form1" name="form1" action="delete-tech.php">
  <p>Choose Technician to Delete:
    <select name="technician" id="technician" title="technician">
    <?php
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($getTechs);
      if($rows > 0) {
          mysqli_data_seek($getTechs, 0);
          $row_getTechs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTechs);
          do {  
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row_getTechs['tech_id']?>"><?php echo $row_getTechs['tech_name']?></option>
    <?php
          }while ($row_getTechs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTechs));
      }
    ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Delete Technician">
  </p>
</form>
```

It should append the information(**list-value**) from the `form` to the URL as you desired. Check it out.

As you say it's not working there is another way using **JavaScript**:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" name="form1" action="delete-tech.php">
  <p>Choose Technician to Delete:
    <select name="technician" id="technician" title="technician">
    <?php
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($getTechs);
      if($rows > 0) {
          mysqli_data_seek($getTechs, 0);
          $row_getTechs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTechs);
          do {  
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row_getTechs['tech_id']?>"><?php echo $row_getTechs['tech_name']?></option>
    <?php
          }while ($row_getTechs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTechs));
      }
    ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="submit" type="button" id="submit" value="Delete Technician" onclick="location.href='delete-tech.php?tech_id='+document.getElementById('technician').value">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: So now if I have my form action as: action="delete-tech.php?tech_id=<?php echo $_POST['technician'];?>"    It will work?

Comment: It still isn't adding the tech_id to the end of the url.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to specify simply `delete-tech.php` as the action. The url will automatically be formatted with form input data. no need to specify the url in the action.

Comment: Yes.  It wouldn't work though.  The URL ended in delete-tech.php

Comment: @SherwoodPro I have added another way to do it. It is supposed to work.

Comment: Yes that worked!  That is some handy javascript!  I appreciate your help Rajesh Paul.  Thanks!  It seems simple stupid now.  : )

Comment: If you actually wanted to make `tech_id` appear in the url you need to use `method='GET'` instead of `method='post'`. Sorry I forgot that. Otherwise the 1st approach was correct. try it now. `POST` method simply hides all the query string from the url

Comment: I was told that using GET was less secure than POST.  But I guess it doesn't really matter when you want the value in the URL anyway.